# One to one and onto function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ define a sequence $(a_n)$ by $a_n=1$ if $n \in A$ and $a_n=0$ is $n\notin A$. Then correspondence $A \rightarrow (a_n)$ is both one one and onto. I am not able to understand the one to one here. What if two different elements are taken from $A$ then both will be mapped onto $1$ .Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get this statement from? Can you please reproduce the original text?

Comment: The "correspondence $A \rightarrow (a_n)$" means the map  $\chi:\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N) \rightarrow 2^{\Bbb N}$ that associates each subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ to a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s. 

The map $\chi$ is one-to-one and onto: 

If $A, B \subset \Bbb N$ and $A \neq B$ then there is an element $x \in A \Delta B$. Let us suppose, without loss of generality, that $x \in A \setminus B$. Then $\chi(A)(x)=1\neq 0 = \chi(B)(x)$. So $\chi(A) \neq \chi(B)$. So $\chi$ is one-to-one.

Comment: For the "onto" part: Given any sequence $(a_n)$ of $0$'s and $1$'s, let us define $A=\{n : a_n=1\}$. It follows immediately that $\chi(A)= (a_n)$. So $\chi$ is onto.

Comment: @KennyWong Real analysis by N. L. Carothers.